Why cannot I generate pairs of numbers from a std::views::iota in c++ 20
I wrote the following function to generate pairs from input ranges.
template <typename Range>
requires std::ranges::borrowed_range<Range>
auto pair(Range && r)
{
    // Creating a range of iterators to the original range
    auto iterator_range = std::views::iota(
      std::ranges::begin(r), 
      std::ranges::end(r));
    return iterator_range
        | std::views::drop(1)
        | std::views::transform([](auto const & it){
            using T = std::ranges::range_reference_t<Range>;
            return std::pair<T,T>(*std::prev(it), *it);
        });
}

It specifically has the constraint borrowed_range against the input so as not to accidentally take non borrowed ranges and get dangling iterators. This works perfectly for an input of std::vector.

auto number_range = std::vector{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        
for(auto [a, b] : pair(number_range))
   std::cout << a << ", " << b << std::endl;          

A reference to a vector is a borrowed range. However I thought I'd test it with an iota range as an input. It too is a borrowed range and because the types stored in the pair are set using using T = std::ranges::range_reference_t<Range>; I figured it would just work. However I was surprised when the below is compiled into an infinite loop.
auto number_range = std::views::iota(0, 10);
        
for(auto [a, b] : pair(number_range))
   std::cout << a << ", " << b << std::endl;
          


What's going on here? The gcc version is linked below and crashes
https://godbolt.org/z/q1EEaj6bW
Is there some undefined behaviour in my code? The clang version is linked below and runs as expected.
https://godbolt.org/z/c3fMqej31
Expected Results
std::vector
0, 1
1, 2
2, 3
3, 4
4, 5
5, 6
6, 7
7, 8
8, 9
std::views::iota
0, 1
1, 2
2, 3
3, 4
4, 5
5, 6
6, 7
7, 8
8, 9


With -fsanitize=address,undefined I get: runtime error: signed integer overflow: 2147483647 + 1 cannot be represented in type 'int' - while clang works fine (also using libstdc++). Odd...

I think the iota view is failing to check it's upper bound and so proceeds until it hits integer overflow. Adding in the sanitize flag checks for overflow.

Yeah, I think so too, but it's surprising that the same library works if used with clang

It works with clang and msvc. Regarding libstdc++, this seems to be an issue with GCCs frontend.

Yeah. MSVC also works. https://godbolt.org/z/nfdvb95Gr

This is disappointing. Discovered this whilst writing a company internal blog post on how neat c++20 ranges are and how std::ranges::iota can be used for lots of nice things.

A slight variation on the code works but will be susceptible to edge cases in the length of the range. https://godbolt.org/z/6zdhTv5xv

Interestingly this works https://godbolt.org/z/PxjesGhEe but this doesn't https://godbolt.org/z/816E85jxs

Nicer with debug iterators, since you get an assertion. But yeah, just only use ranges:: things with ranges code.

This is https://gcc.gnu.org/PR102181 which depends on https://wg21.link/lwg3197

Your code is UB.
std::prev only works with Cpp17BidirectionalIterator, and although the iterator satisfies bidirectional_iterator in the case of iota_view, it does not meet the requirements of Cpp17BidirectionalIterator as its reference is pr-value, so it is just a C++17 input iterator. Applying std::prev to a C++17 input iterator is undefined behavior.
Using ranges::prev works as expected for both compiler.
Demo

So is the answer to always use std::ranges::prev now? Or will std::ranges::prev UB on older typer iterators?

@bradgonesurfing For C++20 ranges always use ranges::prev. ranges::prev already requires a bidirectional_iterator, so the older typer iterators do not satisfy the constraint and will not compile.
